# Make Angular Service Available to All Components

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have a `SpinnerService` class that every single component in my Angular app uses. Is there a way to avoid explicitly injecting it in each component's constructor every time?

Comment: no there isn't a way to do this for good reason.   It would break modularity to save you 15 characters per component that actually needs the class. Every component shouldn't need access to a spinner service.  This sounds more like you should revisit your application design.

Comment: If you are using HttpClientModule I recommend you to try [this package](https://github.com/mpalourdio/ng-http-loader)  for showing spinner on each request. This will eliminate your problem of injecting your service in each component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry mate but that's the only way. Though if you have a hierarchal structure then you can just inject into your root component and send it as input parameter but that's also lead to creating an extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can provide it in your appModule. Remember, whenever you inject and provide anything from appmodule, it is available throughout your application.

Comment: But he's asking to avoid variable in constructor and you're talking about providing it in the appmodule providers.

Comment: He does not want to explicitly inject the service in each of his components. That means, multiple providers, one for each component.

Comment: Sorry @VinodBhavnani, I think I didn't explain myself very well.

Comment: Multiple providers i.e multiple instances are only created when you are providing in providers decorator of each component. When we declare a variable of service in the constructor of component then you are not creating a new instance but using the same instance. Hope it helps you!